# Tablix in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I use a tablix in SSRS 2008 with a Region name and it may contain 10 different regions. Currently, the regions are sorted in the code alphabetically but I have to sort them differently, so I assigned a number to each in the CASE statment based on the desired order. I then sorted the regions by the required order in the tablix itself and the regions are sorted in the desired order in the report but unfortunately, the number assigned is  in the report instead of the region name.  Instead of getting

BF  CF  CO   CL   etc….   I get

1      2      3     4     etc in the heading of the report.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
CASE , 
WHEN teamgroup.Name = 'BF' THEN 1
WHEN teamgroup.Name = 'CF' THEN 2
WHEN teamgroup.Name = 'CO' THEN 3
WHEN teamgroup.Name = 'CL' THEN 4
WHEN teamgroup.Name = 'CN' THEN 5
WHEN teamgroup.Name = 'GA' THEN 6
WHEN teamgroup.Name = 'IN' THEN 7
WHEN teamgroup.Name = 'KY' THEN 8
WHEN teamgroup.Name = 'MD' THEN 9
WHEN teamgroup.Name = 'NF' THEN 10
END AS Region
```

Answer (score 3):

You still need to have `teamgroup.Name` as a column in your resultset, in addition to your sort column. Do this instead:

```
teamgroup.Name AS Region,
CASE
...
END AS Region_Sort
```

And then in your SSRS, add the `Region` column to your Tablix. In the sorting properties for the table, use `Region_Sort`. Make sure not to add `Region_Sort` to your Tablix.